# Stop Google from Indexing files from our second server

Tags: indexing

I'm actually scouring the web for the right terms for this question but after a few hours I decided to post my question here.

The scenario is:
we have a website running on two servers. So the files/website is synchronized in these two servers. We have a second server for internal purposes. Let's name the first server as www and ww2 for the second server. ww2 is automatically updated once the files are updated in www.

Now, Google is indexing the ww2 which I want to stop and just let www be crawled and indexed. My questions are:
1. How can I removed those crawled pages in ww2 removed from Google index?
2. How can I stop google from indexing ww2?

Thanks guys!

Comment: You say the second server is for internal purposes, so why even let Google see this server?  Doesn't it make sense to just restrict ALL access to internals?

Comment: Have you tried the Google Webmaster Tools?

Comment: @kevin Dolan. How can I do that?

Comment: @Cody. I'm not an expert in Google Webmaster tool but when I looked at the links from there, there are no traces of ww2. I can only see results in google index. Any tips?

Comment: @Liza it depends wildly on how you have the server setup. probably the easiest way would be to use a firewall, but more flexible would be various server configuration options.  look into the documentation for your server.

Comment: Hi! Kevin. I understand. I'm not that verse when it comes to server side solution but I understand a little. Are you pertaining to httpd.conf file?

Comment: hello again. We've decided to do a sitewide redirect for now with all requests/links that uses ww2 to www. Anyone who knows the code to be added? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use robots.txt to disallow indexing. And there is a [robots meta tag](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2007/03/using-robots-meta-tag.html) obeyed by google.

Comment: hi jammon. How can I do that? Anything changed in robots.txt of www will also immediately reflect on ww2.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question Google has a removal tool in their Webmaster tools here is a more info about it [Remove page or site from Google's search results](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=164734&from=61062&rd=1)

For the second question you either can use a robots.txt file to block Google from crawling your site (here is a more info [Blocking Google](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=93708)) or you can restrict the access to that server